# Solving ODE with transcendental functions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Here is a MWE for the problem I have:

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] + x + z[x], y[2] == 1}, y, {x, 2, 4}]
```

where `z` is determined by

```
z x^z Log[z] == 1
```

which can't be solved for `z[x]` in simple form.

One possible way is to write ODE for `z[x]` also and solve the coupled differential equations. But for the actual problem at hand, that takes too long. Any suggestions for a different method to solve for `y[x]`?

Answer (score 5):

The DAE-functionality of NDSolve can solve your problem:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] + x + z[x], y[2] == 1,z[x] x^z[x] Log[z[x]] == 1}, {y, z}, {x, 2, 4}]
Plot[{y[x], z[x]} /. sol, {x, 2, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Recommend that you use `Evaluate`, i.e., `Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], z[x]} /. sol], {x, 2, 4}]`